# Питон скрипт не может создать файл на сервере

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Хочу запустить на сервере с убунту 20.04 и апаше2 простенький скрипт на питоне, выглядит вот-так:`with open("hello.txt", "w") as file: file.write("hello world")`
На ПК с виндой все прекрасно работает и файл с Hello world создается, я не очень знаком с архитектурой линукса, могу лишь сказать что запускал все от рута и прописал вайлу permissions 0666 [image: permissions 0666]
Если у кого-то есть идее как это исправить буду очень благодарен)

Comment: Как вы определили, что не может?

Comment: @Эникейщик если запускать через команду python, то не требуется (обычные линуксовые бинарники тоже можно запускать без разрешения на выполнение через какой-нибудь ld-linux)

Comment: запускаю его командой python3 и путь к файлу, в моем случае /var/www/html/test.py там где изначально находился index который создает apache

Comment: @andreymal ну как я сказал на ПК все работает как надо а на линуксе уже нет, я добавил после этого принт чтобы проверить что он вообще запускается и да, он запускается но файл не создает.

Comment: @user542977 может, файл создаётся не в той папке, в которой вы ожидаете? Вы точно проверяете наличие файла в текущей рабочей папке?

Comment: нашелься в /root/, спасибо большое! Не знаете как сделать чтобы он сам в /var/www/html/ переносился автоматически? Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Ну либо указывайте при открытии файла полный путь, либо перед запуском скрипта делайте переход в нужный каталог, чтобы он стал текущим.